# iis url-rewrite issue with file paths

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

in a folder named **project** i have a .php file which can take parameters.

i'm using this rule:

```
<rule name="Friendly" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^phrasecat/(.+)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?phrasecat={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

in order to redirect requests like this:

```
www.domain.com/project/phrasecat/word1
```

to

```
www.domain.com/project/index.php?phrasecat=word1
```

this is done in order to have friendly urls.

it works, but the problem is, IIS thinks phrasecat is a real directory so all included files ( javascript/ css/ images ) do not get included because phrasecat folder does not exist and so everything is garbled.

is there any way around this through redirection rules? I don't want to manually create the folder and place there for a second time the resources.

thank you in advance

Comment: Surely this is more of an issue as to how you are referencing the css, js etc in the first place? I use the same rule as above all the time, and just make sure I reference everything using the root slash, i.e /css/, instead of trying to traverse using ../../ etc.